# How to add a route that will render a component using react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

Presently, the following code is in the component `SinglePostPage`:

```js
        <section>
            <article className="post">
                <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                <p className="post-content">{post.content}</p>
                <Link to={`editPost/${post.id}`} className="button">
                    Edit Post
                </Link>
            </article>
        </section>
```

The `EditPostForm` component contains the form to edit a post.
How can I add a route to render the `EditPostForm` component when someone clicks on the `Link`?

My `App.js` is as follows:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <AddPostForm/>
                <PostsList/>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          />
          <Route exact path="/posts/:postId" component={SinglePostPage} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just add a new route to App.js. For example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <AddPostForm/>
                <PostsList/>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          />
          <Route exact path="/posts/:postId" component={SinglePostPage} />
          <Route exact path="/editPost/:id" component={EditPostForm} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

and then in SinglePostPage your path for the link is slightly wrong, it should be:

```
<Link to={`/editPost/${post.id}`}>...</Link>
```

You were missing first '/'

Comment: Tried that, but the `<Link>` now redirects to the home view

Comment: I tried removing the line `<Redirect to="/" />` but then the `<Link>` navigates to the URL `http://localhost:3000/posts/editPost/1` which does not have any content.

Comment: @Harish Ok can you create a reproducible version on code sandbox so I can debug. thanks

Comment: I will try to create a Codepen. If you want to see the rest of the application, it's in this tutorial: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data

Comment: @Harish Thanks I have updated my answer which should now be working. I think you were missing part of the path in the link

Comment: Yes! updating the Link solved my problem.